# Mark up navigation elements with Microdata / Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

I understand using microdata to highlight a thing, person, movie etc.

I think you should also highlight key pages, such as the 'About' page and 'Contact' page.

I've heard you should markup navigation areas too. I suppose this is a good idea as it can tell Google the areas which aren't important.

How would I do this? Is it just a case of wrapping a div around each nav bar etc?

Is it important? Does anybody else use it?

Comment: What is wrong with the HTML5 element `nav`?

Answer (score 1):

As navigation items are links, one way is to use itemprop "url" (dependant on the itemscope). For creativework you may also use "isBasedOnUrl."

You may also try nesting.